# Notice: Undefined index: session PHP

Tags: php

This error only shows if user is not logged-in.  I understand there are already a couple of errors like this, ive tried my best to test them all. but i still cant figure this out.

*Notice: Undefined index: user_session in ..index.php on line 10*

```
<?php 
session_start();

if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE){
    header('Location: index.php');
}

if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
   $session = $_SESSION['user_session']; //line 10
}
```

Comment: have you set the value in the session variable already. Try `print_r($_SESSION)` to check whether the variable is there in the session array.

Comment: After header location you must die )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user logs in , you have to set this `$_SESSION["user_session"]=$value;` first then only you will be able to access it. You are trying to access a variable which you haven't set anywhere. So its throwing undefined index.

Comment: I tried Sagar's code below and it introduced a new error which led me to the point you're trying to say. the `$_SESSION` array doesn't contain any value.

Comment: Also in future make sure you use isset() before assigning any value to a variable. In bigger projects it becomes a pain to debug those bugs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to fix this error message then please try following code, Your code changes like this:

```
<?php 
session_start();

if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE){
header('Location: index.php');
}

if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
if( isset($_SESSION['user_session']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_session']) ) 
$session = $_SESSION['user_session']; //line 10
}
```